# SQL join returns all values from the wrong table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I cannot figure out why my SQL result returns all data from the wrong table. I want to receive all data from product table but I want to filter the results so it does not show those results that have some value in another table.

My SQL statement is:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM orders 
       JOIN products 
           ON orders.product_id=products.product_id 
           AND NOT order_date=somedate;
```

This query returns everything from the orders table where somedate is not the given value but I want to get everything from the products table if orders table does not have the given somedate as value (when the product is not reserved).

Edit: thanks for the help everyone! each answer worked perfectly for me with some slight modifications :)

Comment: can you post the sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get products which don't have orders of a certain criteria (`order_date != somedate`) like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.product_id = p.product_id AND order_date != somedate 
WHERE o.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got your question right, but you can try this:

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM orders 
       JOIN products 
           ON orders.product_id=products.product_id 
 WHERE order_date<>somedate;
```

Comment: I think you pretty much got it :) That statement also has the same problem, I get all data from orders table where order date is not the given value. I want to get all data from products table

Comment: thanks for the help! it was ok with slight modifications Vatev had

Answer (score 1):

Different orders could have different dates.  If you want products that were *not* ordered on a particular date, then try phrasing the query like this:

If I understand correctly, your original query returned all products with multiple orders, because some orders were on that date and some were not.

```
select p.* 
  from product p 
 where not exists (select 1 
                     from orders o 
                    where o.product_id = p.product_id 
                          and o.order_date = somedate)
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of the answer.  StackOverflow is not letting me edit the post so looks prettier.